# Should all objects in a vector have a copy constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

I read somewhere that objects that are already in a vector, are copied when the vector is reallocated.

Why is this ? Shouldn't they just be moved ? Also, does this mean that one is expected to write a copy constructor for objects stored in vectors ?

Comment: It's pretty clearly stated [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Since c++11 it's enough the elements meet the `Erasable` concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

Until the advent of C++11 the elements of a vector must met the requirements of [**CopyAssignable**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable) and [**CopyConstructible**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyConstructible).

From C++11 and until C++17 the requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual operations performed on the container. Generally, it is required that element type is a complete type and meets the requirements of [**Erasable**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Erasable), but many member functions impose stricter requirements.

From C++17 and beyond the requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual operations performed on the container. Generally, it is required that element type meets the requirements of [**Erasable**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Erasable), but many member functions impose stricter requirements. This container (but not its members) can be instantiated with an incomplete element type if the allocator satisfies the allocator completeness requirements.